# Unused parameters in Java with array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

I am writing a program that splits an even length array down the middle and finds the largest of the two halves. This is the code I have so far, however i'm not sure what to pass as the first parameter in the calculateAverage method. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
public int calculateAverage(int[] scores, int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        score += scores[i];
        count++;
    }

    score = (score / count);

    return score;
}

public int scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
    int endOfFirstHalf = (scores.length / 2) - 1;
    int firstHalf = calculateAverage(scores[], scores[0], endOfFirstHalf);
    int secondHalf = calculateAverage(scores[], scores[scores.length / 2],     scores[scores.length - 1]);

    if (firstHalf < secondHalf) {
        return secondHalf;
    } else {
        return firstHalf;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a method which you don't know why you have it ? What did you actually write in this ?

Comment: Good point @Dici... you have to pass the `scores` array from the `scoresAverage` metode to the `calculateAverage` methode

Comment: For your calls to `calculateAverage` I would pass `(scores, 0, endOfFirstHalf);` and `(scores, endOfFirstHalf, scores.Length);`

Comment: Your second method doesn't calculate the average. Even if you pass the correct arguments to `caculateAverage` (which you don't), it would return the average of half of the array that has a higher average.

Comment: I simply want to return the half with the highest average not return the average. I have updated the code to what i have. I just get an error with the first parameter of the calculateAverage method as i am not sure what to pass into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this.

```
public class TestBench{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] i = {1,2,3,4};
            System.out.println(scoresAverage(i));
       }

        public static double calculateAverage(int[] scores, int start, int end) {
            int count = 0;
            double score = 0.0;
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                score += scores[i];
                count++;
            }
            score = (score / count);

            return score;
        }

        public static double scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
            int endOfFirstHalf = (scores.length / 2) - 1;
            double firstHalf = calculateAverage(scores, 0, endOfFirstHalf);
            double secondHalf = calculateAverage(scores, endOfFirstHalf + 1, scores.length - 1);

            if (firstHalf < secondHalf) {
                return secondHalf;
            } else {
                return firstHalf;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int secondHalf = calculateAverage(scores[scores.length / 2], 
                                        scores[scores.length - 1]);
```

1.you have a typo in method name.

2.pass an array name. There should be 3 parameters, not 2.

it should look somewhat like that:

```
int firstHalf = calculateAverage(scores, 0, endOfFirstHalf);
    int secondHalf = calculateAverage(scores,scores[scores.length / 2], 
                                            scores[scores.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass what ever your function is expecting. Anyway, here is the modified code:

```
public class UnusedParam {
public int calculateAverage(int[] scores, int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        score += scores[i];
        count++;
    }
    score = (score / count);

    return score;
}

public int scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
    int endOfFirstHalf = (scores.length / 2) - 1;
    int firstHalf = calculateAverage(scores, 0, endOfFirstHalf);
    int secondHalf = calculateAverage(scores,scores.length / 2, scores.length - 1);

    if (firstHalf == secondHalf) {
        System.out.print("First Half is the same as Second Half");
        return secondHalf;
    }
    else if (firstHalf < secondHalf) {
        System.out.print("Second Half is the largest");
        return secondHalf;
    } 
    else {
        System.out.print("First Half is the largest");
        return firstHalf;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] scores = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    UnusedParam up = new UnusedParam();
    int retVal = up.scoresAverage(scores);
    System.out.println(", "+retVal);
}
}
```

Comment: what is the value returned in if block and else block of scoresAverage() method? doesn't both the same?